# How to reverse engineering a proguarded .apk?

Tags: disassembly, android, apk, dalvik

Lets say you have android1.apk file coded with proguard enable.

I want to reverse engineer it in such a way that it shows the original methods names instead letters of alphabets, example bellow

public void setName()
{

}

On android1.apk file that was coded with proguard enabled, once you reverse engineer the apk, you will get the java code in the format bellow:

public void a()
{

}

a() being setName()

Answer (score 5):

Without the proguard mapping, this is not possible. That information is simply no longer contained in the dex file.

The best you could do would be to manually rename the methods, etc. with your own names.